# How to align a div to the right of an iframe?

Tags: html, css, jsp, iframe

In my JSP I have an iframe and a div. The div has 4 buttons.

```
<iframe id="iframe_role" src="" width="75%" height="75%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1">
</iframe>

<br><br>

<div id="div_buttons">  
   <button type="submit" id="button_add">Add Role</button>  
   <button type="submit" id="button_edit">Edit Role</button>    
   <button type="submit" id="button_delete">Delete Role</button>    
   <button type="submit" id="button_refresh">Refresh</button> 
</div>
```

I want to align the div to the right of iframe so that the right side of iframe is aligned with right side of Refresh button.

I tried using align attribute of div:

```
<div id="div_buttons" align="right">
```

but it aligned the div to right of the browser window.

How can I align the div to the right of the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the div as wide as the `iframe`, (in this case 75%), and set the `text-align` property to `right`:

**Tip:** *You should no longer use inline attributes to set layout properties such as height or width... This should be managed by css:*

```css
#iframe_role {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#div_buttons {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe_role" src="" frameborder="1">
</iframe>

<br><br>

<div id="div_buttons">  
  <button type="submit" id="button_add">Add Role</button>  
  <button type="submit" id="button_edit">Edit Role</button>    
  <button type="submit" id="button_delete">Delete Role</button>    
  <button type="submit" id="button_refresh">Refresh</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks. One question: What is the `overflow` attribute of `iframe` for? Is it same as `scrolling` attribute? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Yes... The `overflow` property sets how will the element handle the inner content that exceeds it's size (scroll, hidden, visible). The difference is that visual attributes defined inline on the element (such as `width=""`, `height=""` or `scrolling=""`) are obsolete. These should be defined with css properties.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, you can mark it as the correct answer. Hope you achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to do something like this:

iframe styles:

```
float: right;
margin-right: 50px;
```

buttons container styles:

```
float: right;
margin-right: 50px;
```

Or other ways with css

Comment: Can you give a code example where you use these styles?